# Copy and change item names in chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to Copy a chests contents over and then change the display names of all the items in the chest.

I can easily do the first part by /clone.

I have been trying to do this part with the /blockdata command like this.

```
/blockdata -505 69 471 {Items:{display:{Name:"Altered_Item"}}}
```

I also tried some other variants. The method above removes all the items in the chest though. 
Is there a way without knowing the item ids to change just the display name of every item in the chest ?

Comment: Well, you could take them out of the chest and rename them in an anvil, if you like.

Comment: @GiantTree I'm trying to do it with command blocks

Comment: Is `/replaceitem` what you need? It lets you replace a specific slot inside a chest with another item. You can also add `dataTags` to rename them. If yes, I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I don't think that will work. I will not know the items in the chest. I need to rename them all. I was hoping there was a dynamic way to rename items without knowing the item id.

Comment: I think this is not possible, because you need to ow the items with blockdata and replace item

Answer (score 1):

Does this need to happen particularly quickly? Because if not, you could summon tnt or a fireball to destroy the cloned chest so it drops its items, use `/entitydata` to change their display names, then teleport them to a hopper above another chest. This is a comparatively slow workaround and leaves you with an extra chest (the cloned one that was destroyed will drop as an item), but you can't edit an item's data without completely overwriting it unless it's in entity form. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd like to suggest using `/setblock <x> <y> <z> air 0 destroy` instead, since you don't need to rely on tnt or a fireball to destroy a chest. also, this way you'll surely never destroy any surroundings without having to build a perimeter around it.

Comment: Very good point, not sure why my first thought was an explosion.

Answer (score 1):

### 1.14+

Evolution of commands has made this possible using the `/data modify` command.

```
/data modify block Cx Cy Cz Items[].display.Name set value '{"text":"The Item"}'
```

This command will set *all* item's name to `The Item`.

But, if you only want to target an item in a specific slot, use this command:

```
/data modify block Cx Cy Cz Items[{Slot:1b}].display.Name set value '{"text":"The Item"}'
```

Replace the number in `Slot:1b` with the desired slot.